# Compute CPU and memory usage of a Java class without actually executing the class

Tags: java, profiling

I have to design a client server system where a valid Java .Class file will be provided by the user. The catch is, the class file should either be executed on the client or the server side based on the following criteria :

- If network latency + execution time on server < execution time of client then it'll be executed remotely on the server and the result returned to client else it'll be executed locally on the client itself
- It is assumed that the configuration of client will be lower than the configuration of the server. Configuration considered here is RAM and Processor
- The dynamic code in light here, that is to be executed, is a resource hungry code like N Queens, Traveling salesman, etc.

My project is based on dynamic class loading in Java. I'm using TCP connection to establish communication between client and server.

It would be really helpful if you guys can provide me with something that will allow me to get the amount of resources that will be consumed by the class file upon execution without actually executing it.

My mentor says to profile the code to get the amount of resource used but I can't seem to find any profiling API or any such procedure to get the CPU and memory usage of the code at run time. All I have managed to find are external  profiling tools. If you guys can shed some light on how to achieve internal profiling through code that will also be helpful

Comment: Looks like you want to bound time and space complexity just by code profiling, estimating running time without even knowing the input, doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do like this for the general case, see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem . Are you sure that you actually should not execute and profile the code for typical cases to get characteristic resource values for your code?

Comment: This might be hard, if not impossible (see: [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) internally before the program has executed at least once. You may have to just profile previous execution times at each location and decide off of historical averages... :(... If the possible .class files are known in advance (limited set) than perhaps you can set up some VMs with different specs and do some scripted experimentation to reference against and make an informed guess programatically.

Comment: Sorry for the procedure on which I was asking help. I have no clue about any of this, that's why I might have framed a vague question.

Comment: So, I should profile the code on a configuration and store the result of the configuration say in a database. I should sample such values for different configurations and prepare a database off of it. Then use this database  later to determine a performance of the code on a new configuration and act accordingly?